# Conflict with basename and Redirect with build in react

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

I have some conflicts with routes, BrowserRouter, Redirect with the build of the page.

The first detected issue is if I don't configure the basename or

```
basename={'/'}
```

then, when I make build I got the blank page.

Now, If I put `basename={window.location.pathname || ''}`

```
<BrowserRouter basename={window.location.pathname || ''}>
    <App />
  </BrowserRouter>
```

then, when I make build my project works but.

Another conflict is if I put

```
    <Switch>
        <Redirect exact from="/" to="test" component={ test } />
        <Route path="/" exact component={ test } />
        <Route path="/test2" component={ test2 } />
        <Route path="/test3" component={ test3 } /
    </Switch>
```

I add Redirect because I want a path be loaded by default.  It works, but then when I make build I got again the blank page. If I remove the Redirect the page after build works but then I didn't have a path by default.  What is wrong?

Also, It seems the redirect has a bug because every time when I reload my page, affects the paths

Ej:  "localhost:3000/test

when I reload the page:

```
 "localhost:3000/test/test"
```

and if I reload again, I got:

```
 "localhost:3000/test/test/test and so on.
```

In my package.json I have configured "homepage": ".", like is suggested in many related forums.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1):

I think this will help

```
 <BrowserRouter>   
    <Switch>
          <Redirect from="/" to="/test" exact/>
          <Route path ="/test" exact component ={test} />
          <Route path="/test2" component={test2} />
          <Route path="/test3" component={test3} />
      </Switch>
    </BrowserRouter>
```

you don't need this route  `<Route path="/" exact component={ test } />`
also you needed to add `/` before `test`

Comment: When I reload (for each reload) the page, add /test to the path(first-reload: localhost:3000/test; 2nd: localhost:3000/test/test and so on).  It seems is because of the redirect.  How can I prevent that?

Comment: if I remove basename={window.location.pathname || ''} works but then when I build the project got a blank page.

Comment: try `basename="/"` or `basename="/test"`

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  If I try that, when I build the project I o got a blank page.

Comment: I don't understand why I get a blank page if I put  basename="/" or basename="/test" or if I don't put <BrowserRouter> without any basename.

Comment: Hi.  I was trying to open the application after build with double-clicking the index.html and didn't work either, I got the blank page  but if the built files are run in a server environment works.  https://create-react-app.dev/docs/deployment/.  That was my problem.